# Electrolysis of AgNo3

Tags: redox, electrolysis, silver

I have a solution of $\ce{AgNO_3}$ (is diluted with water). I electrolyse it. What products from at anode and cathode.

Answer (score 4):

You would get silver at the cathode, and oxygen at the anode.

Since silver is below hydrogen in the spectrochemical series,it tends to get reduced over hydrogen, similarly, since $\ce{NO3-}$ is above $\ce{OH-}$ , it tends not to get oxidised, therefore giving oxygen.

$\ce{Ag+ + e- -> Ag}$ (at cathode)

$\ce{ 4OH- -> O2 + 2H2O + 4e-}$ (at anode)

Comment: But isnt the Voltage for NO3-  (+0.96) which is above Ag (+0.80)?? @Supernova. there fore NO3- will reduce. can u give the acutal voltage of the half reactions if i got it wrong.

Comment: lets just put it like this, you go to a mall, and do some shopping with your dad. Now you see Bill gates(who is in a mood to help out anyone who asks him) there. You shop all you want, but see that you forgot your wallet, and then at the end, you approach him, and he says,"I'll take care of the bill, you can leave if you want". Now consider a different scenario, where you see a rather poor dude standing there while you wereshopping. Now if you request him to pay for you, that would put him in a much more unstable state, that what Bill gates wouldve faced

Comment: This is somewhat similar to what happens when you have both $\ce{OH-}$ and $\ce{NO3-}$ in the medium. With $\ce{Ag}$ at the other side @KierenAlbuquerque

Comment: @Supernova, marvelous analogy